# smoking chicken know how

Tags: chicken

I would like to make smoked chicken as it is not available here in UK - I used to be able to get it in S.A. and I think it is fab. I live in a small flat in cold, very cold UK.  My question is;
Can I smoke chicken breast in a "Go Chef" cooker or my oven maybe and how would I go about it if I do not have a smoker. (do not have space for one) I read somewhere that you should cook the chicken first and then smoke it, is this correct?  Thanks. Rose

Comment: Just so you know, you can definitely buy it here in the UK :-)

Comment: A pressure smoker works well in indoor environments, but your flat will still reek of smoke.

Answer (score 2):

I could find nothing on a "Go Chef Cooker" so I cannot speak for that.  When I did the search, I found some Pressure Cookers, and those won't be a very viable choice for smoking foods.

There are a couple of ways that you can smoke meats indoors.

One of the ways is to do it in the oven.  There is a "smoker" box that is used for indoor smoking.  The box contains a rack and the smoker chips sit below the rack in the bottom of the box, while the meat sits on the rack suspended in the box.  The oven causes the chips to smoke. But, because it is completely enclosed (sealed), the smoke does not infiltrate the kitchen/house.  When you open it, after cooking, you might want to open it outdoors so that the smoke is not released indoors.  I also suspect that the cooking time might vary because it is a different method of cooking. Note: I do not have one. I use an electric outdoor smoker. My FIL uses a smoker that is a 30" diameter steel pipe mounted on an old axle with wheels, tires, a trailer hitch, & a license plate.  I expect this will be your best bet for smoking without an appliance that belongs outdoors.

Another way would be to have an indoor grill, like a Jenn-Air range with a cooktop that has burner racks and a downdraft exhaust. But, this is only good for grilling thin meats & I would not expect them to give much smoke flavor to a bird.

Another way would be to use some Liquid Smoke type product.  With this, you could use it in a baste or marinade, then simply bake in the oven as you would any bird.  Doing this will give you a couple of limited choices on flavor, like Hickory or Mesquite, but using real wood chips in a physical smoker (either stove top or outdoors) will give you the option to vary the flavor by using some pecan, oak, apple, cherry, or other woods.  Doing a search for "stovetop smoker" will provide some good results.